# How can i pass config file parameters in Google Cloud Platform Spark Scala jobs?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I have a Spark Scala job deployed on GCP Dataproc cluster. How can I pass config file as a parameter to the Spark Submit query using the Web UI?

Comment: You have to show what you have tried.

Comment: Without additional details, I can not answer this question. Next information would be useful to give an answer: 1) What config file do you want to pass as a parameter? 2) Is this config and parameter for your job, not for Spark? 3) How you will do the same using `spark-submit` command?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean the equivalent of what is noted [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#loading-configuration-from-a-file) adapted for a Spark job ran in a dataproc cluster. In order to do this, you would have to override the `spark-defaults.conf` file which is contained by default in the dataproc cluster. This has to be done in the cluster creation step but there's no way to do it directly via the Web UI. Instead, you need to pass your new configuration file as a value for the `--properties` flag in a `gcloud dataproc clusters create` command like so:

```
gcloud dataproc clusters create $CLUSTER_NAME --properties=spark:spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=yourfile.conf
```

Actually you don't even have to begin writing the `gcloud` command yourself, you can fill in everything in the Console/Web UI "Create a Cluster" view, click on "Equivalent command line" from the bottom of the page, add the `--properties=...` part and *then* run it from a shell.

**Update**

In the above answer I focused on the fact that you wanted to use a config **file**. However, if you actually want to edit configuration parameters via the Console on the Job level you can also do so by providing key:value property pairs which will override the ones in the `spark-defaults.conf` file.[image]